# ExtJS 4, CheckboxGroup. Table layout

Tags: templates, extjs4

I'm using ExtJS 4.1 MVC. In view I created checkboxGroup and in controller I add items (checkboxes) to id dynamically. But I need them to display in special way. I'm thinking about Templates (XTemplates).

Do I need to add `tpl` to checkboxGroup or to every checkbox item? I have no idea how does it look like. 
Please, help!

Please write an example template for checkbox

```
var checkboxes = Ext.getCmp("myCheckboxGroup");
myStore.each(function(item){
    var name = item.get("name"); 
    checkboxes.add({
        boxLabel: name,
        name: fieldName,
        // tpl ???
    });
},this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better approach - for **CheckboxGroup** make a **Table Layout**. It looks like this:

View:

```
xtype: "checkboxgroup",
layout: {
    type: "table",
    columns: 3
},
defaults : {
    padding : "0 10 0 0",
    width : 233,
    cellCls : 'verticalAlignTop',   // <=====
    border : false,         // <=====
},
width: 700,
items: []
```

In controller I dynamically add items:

```
var checkboxes = Ext.getCmp("myCheckboxGroup");
myStore.each(function(item){
    var name = item.get("name"); 
    checkboxes.add({
        xtype: "checkbox",
        boxLabel: name,
        name: fieldName,
    });
},this);
```

And to make a vertical align I added `cellCls : 'verticalAlignTop'` and in `style.css` add:

```
.verticalAlignTop { vertical-align:top; }
```

Works great for me:
[image]